# Backbone View events not firing after the view is replaced, then put back on the page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views, backbone-relational

## Problem:

Events that are set inside a view are not firing after the view is replaced with something else using `$element.html(anotherView)` and then put back on the page using `#element.html(theView)`.

**Example:**

```
var BuggyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Event works the at first, but not after the view is replaced, then added back
    //     onto the page
    events:{
        'click #some-element': 'on_click_some_element'
    },
    // This function gets called before the view is replaced by another view, but
    //     not after it is added back into the page the second time
    on_click_some_element:function(event){
        alert('User clicked "some element"');
    }
});
```

The events work after this code executes:

```
// Create the new view:
var buggyView = new BuggyView({});
// Add the view to the page
$element.html(buggyView.el);
```

This code would happen later when the view is replaced on the page with something else:

```
$element.html(anotherView.el);
```

After the view is added back onto the page, the events no longer work:

```
$element.html(buggyView.el);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely when you are removing your view you are also removing the views' bound events, You probably need to either [redelgate your events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents). or instead of using the (jquery) .[remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) use [.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/).

Comment: The isn't being removed, its being replaced with something else using $element.html(anotherView.el)

Comment: Where is your `BuggYView el` while it's being replaced with `anotherView`? Also did you try  calling delegateEvents after replacing the `buggyView el`?

Comment: Adding .delagateEvents() worked. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Run render after set the element of the view in the DOM:

```
$element.html(anotherView.el);
anotherView.render();

$element.html(theView.el);
theView.render();
```

Probably your issue is that the render did not run again. You are only switching the DOM assignment.

Comment: The render() did not work, but adding delagateEvents() did work. Thanks anyway though!